# Add multiple radiogroups in DT

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I have been wondering if it is possible to add two (or more) radiogroup buttons in a DT table in shiny.
From this page, it seems that adding one is quite simple : https://rstudio.github.io/DT/011-radio.html

Nevertheless, I am struggling with the possibility to add two radiogroups. Here is my code :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- bootstrapPage(DT::dataTableOutput("DT_table"))

server <- function(input, output) {

output$DT_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
m <- matrix(
  as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:5])
)

n <- matrix(
  as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(month.abb, paste("P", LETTERS[1:5], sep = "_"))
)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
  m[i, ] = sprintf(
    '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
    month.abb[i], m[i, ]
  )
}

for (i in seq_len(nrow(n))) {
  n[i, ] = sprintf(
    '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
    paste0("T2", month.abb[i]), n[i, ]
  )
}

dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(m, n))
DT::datatable(dataset, selection = 'none', escape = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
          callback = DT::JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
      var $this = $(this.node());
      $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
      $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
    });
    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
)}, server = FALSE)

observe({
  print(input$Jan)
  print(input$T2Jan)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I clearly see that the problem is coming from my callback argument, which is applying the shiny-input-radiogroup/id to the whole row and not to each radiogroup of each row. As you can see, my input$T2Jan is always NULL. I am really new to javascript so I have no idea where to start.

Do you think it is feasible with a little bit of javascript manipulation, or is it better to just create another datatable next to the first one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `callback`:

```
callback <- c(
  "  $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){",
  "    var name = $(this).attr('name');",
  "    var value = $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked').val();",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue(name, value);",
  "  });"
)
```

and:

```
DT::datatable(dataset, selection = 'none', escape = FALSE, 
              options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
              callback = JS(callback) 
)
```